# How to add JSON String to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone

How to add JSON String to NSDictionary ?

```
 NSString *j_String  @"{ "comp": [
      { "id": "1" },
      { "id": "2" },
      { "id": "3" }
     ],
    "contact": [
      { "mail": "some@email.com", "name": "Name"  },
      { "mail": "email@email.com", "name": "Name"  }
     ]
    }";

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:@"nvjd" forKey:j_String];
```

can i do this way to add Json String into NSMutableDictionary or NSDictionary!

Comment: convert string into nsdata and then use nsjsonseriealization and pass data it will return dictionary.

Comment: you can use default SBJSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Json String into NSobject using SBJSON. And then add to your own dictionary. If we want to take Json stirng form this, Just Use convert Json writer method from SBJson Class.

Answer (score 0):

Add SBJson library in your project you can download it from [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/), and than use this code in your .m file

```
#import "SBJson.h"

   SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
   NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString: j_String error:nil];

   NSLog(@"json data is : %@",jsonData);
```